# Django form saving all values to 0 when I change just one

Tags: django, django-forms

Here is a form question. I am creating a grid of forms populated by model data. This is generated based on code that looks for an "Allocation" record with a user ID that also contains a date inside of a date range. If no "Allocation" record exists a field is generated with a 0. Upon saving any fields that have allocations records should be updated if changed, and any fields that don't have allocation records should create an allocation record if changed.

The problem: When I change a number and press save, all existing allocation records get updated to 0.

What am I doing wrong?

models.py

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    weekly_capacity = models.IntegerField()

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class Allocation(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    week = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    allocated_hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    actual_hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

project_profile.py

```
def resource_allocation_by_week(start,end):
    users_on_project = Allocation.objects.filter(project_id=offset)
    users_in_date_range = users_on_project.filter(week__range=[start, end])
    dict_of_user_hours = {}
    for i in users_on_project:
        total_weeks_allo = 0
        for a in Allocation.objects.filter(week__range=[start, end]).filter(user_id=i.user_id):
            total_weeks_allo += a.allocated_hours


        allocated_total = i.user_id.weekly_capacity - total_weeks_allo
        allocated_by_date = users_in_date_range.filter(user_id=i.user_id).values_list('allocated_hours', flat=True)


        if users_in_date_range.filter(user_id=i.user_id).exists():
            Allocation_pk = users_in_date_range.filter(user_id=i.user_id).values_list('id', flat=True)
            f_inst = Allocation.objects.get(pk=Allocation_pk[0])
            allocation_form = edit_resource_allocation(instance = f_inst)
            dict_of_user_hours[i.user_id] = (allocation_form.as_p, allocated_by_date[0], allocated_total)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                allocation_form = edit_resource_allocation(request.POST, instance = f_inst)
                if allocation_form.is_valid():
                    if allocation_form.has_changed():
                        allocation_form.save()

        else:

            non_displayed_form_values = Allocation(
                user_id = i.user_id,
                project_id = i.project_id,
                week = start,
                actual_hours = 0,
                )
            allocation_form_new = edit_resource_allocation(instance=non_displayed_form_values, initial={'allocated_hours' : 0})
            dict_of_user_hours[i.user_id] = (allocation_form_new.as_p, 0, allocated_total)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                allocation_form_new = edit_resource_allocation(request.POST, instance=non_displayed_form_values, initial={'allocated_hours' : 0})
                dict_of_user_hours[i.user_id] = (allocation_form_new.as_p, 0, allocated_total)
                if allocation_form_new.is_valid():
                    if allocation_form_new.has_changed():
                        allocation_form_new.save()
```

forms.py

```
class edit_resource_allocation(ModelForm):
    allocated_hours = forms.IntegerField(label='', required=False,)

    class Meta:
        model = Allocation
        exclude = ['user_id', 'project_id', 'week', 'actual_hours']
```

project_profile.html

```
<table>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for obj in resource_allocation_grid %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ obj.0|date:"D m/d/Y" }} - {{ obj.1|date:"D m/d/Y" }}
        </td>
        {% for i, v in obj.2.items %}
        <td>
            {{v.0}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{v.2}}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}

    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</table>
```

Here is what the end result currently looks like. (Looks good, just doesn't work)

[image: Form screen shot]

Comment: Please try to supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Selcuk I have edited the post and tried to simplify the code the best I can. I also added the related code and reworded the question for clarity.

Comment: If you have multiple forms in the same `<form>` tag, you need to use [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix). You might find [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/) useful, although that would probably require more changes to your code.

Comment: @Alasdair, thanks for pointing me in the direction of the prefix. This worked for all fields that have model objects. Still working out how to get a unique prefix for the fields without existing model objects. Tried creating a random iteration variable but that did not seem to work. I'll post the final answer when I get it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to work with `Prefix` inside for the `<form>` tag. I was able to do this by creating a unique string for each record regardless of if it existed or not.

```
unique_id = "%s%s" % (start, i.user_id)
```

Thanks for the help @Alasdair

Note: I tried to use a `uuid.uuid4()` to generate a unique value, but discovered that each time the variable was called it would generate a new ID. I needed to use this unique ID in several places so this did not solve the issue. Much better to have the prefix tied to data I think.